# Change ng-switch using ng-click inside ng-repeat blocks

Tags: angularjs

I have this ng-repeat block

```
<div ng-repeat="block in blocks" id="{{block.id}}">
<div ng-switch on="mode">
    <div ng-switch-when="a">
        {{block.text}}
        <div ng-click="mode='a'"></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="b">
        {{block.image}}
        <div ng-click="mode='b'"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which will generates 3 of the above with id Block1 Block2 Block3.

Each block has 2 modes of displaying, which are text mode and image mode.

How do i make it, or what kind of expression that i can use, so that if i click the ng-click, it will only change the mode for that particular block where i pressed it? In this case, if i click it from Block1, it will only change the display mode for Block1?

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/XSOqPQdMHTcXtpmdygX4

Comment: Due to `ng-repeat` child scope, what is shown should already change each instance individually since `mode` is a primitive. Create a plunker demo that replicates your problem

Comment: @charlietfl here is the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/XSOqPQdMHTcXtpmdygX4